# ¿Cómo agregar datos a un objeto que contiene un objeto dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas tardes espero mi pregunta no sea confusa y si lo es con la descripción se dará a entender, primero que nada miremos este array.

```js
const recursos = [
{
  data: {nombre: "juan", apellido: "cepeda"},
  component: Component
},
{
  data: {nombre: "ricardo", apellido: "mejia"},
  component: Component
}
]
```

con esta estructura necesito trabajar y pues que pasa que de la base de datos necesito llenar mi arreglo con esos datos, de la base de datos pues recibo los datos así.

```js
const datosDb = [
{
  nombre: "juan",
  apellido: "cepeda"
},
{
  nombre: "ricardo",
  apellido: "mejia"
}
]
```

ahora bien, necesito que dentro de cada data dentro de recursos se llene con un objeto, puede se en el mismo orden dentro del array.
puedo pensar que necesitaría la estructura básica vacía, de este modo.

```js
const recursos = [
{
  data: {},
  component: Component
}
]
```

y intentar no se algo asi.

```js
let numberMaxObject: number = recursos.length;

let i: number = 0;

while (i < numberMaxObject) {
    recursos.find(object => funcion(){
      object.data = array[i]
    })
    i++;
}
```

sinceramente se que esto no funcionaria así pero fue lo único que se me ocurrió y intente o pensé que por hay tengo que hacerlo ósea de una forma parecida o de pronto hay otro modo y me estoy complicando mucho pero bueno hay dejo eso que fue lo único que intente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un spread operator, un spread operator lo que hace es de manera simple; agregar las propiedades que están dentro de un objeto a otro. Lo que hice en el código fue inicializar un arreglo vacío, y con el arreglo del que recibo los datos de la DB, le apliqué un forEach (método que básicamente funciona como un for dentro de un arreglo) y a este arreglo vacío (recursos) le hice push 2 propiedades, data que recibe el objeto nuevo, y component que recibe Component.
Espero te haya ayudado.

```js
const recursos = []
const datosDb = [
{
  nombre: "juan",
  apellido: "cepeda"
},
{
  nombre: "ricardo",
  apellido: "mejia"
}
]
let Component

datosDb.forEach(element => {
    recursos.push({
    data: {...element},
    component: Component
  })
})
```